# R, plot , font size changes in multiple plot figures

Tags: r, plot, resolution, font-size

I am creating graphs for a publication and would like them to have the same font size.

When I create a figure with **multiple plots**, the **font size decreases** even though I haven't changed the `tiff()` resolution or `pointsize` parameter.
I increased the figure size according to ultimately fit the number of plots, and made sure the margins are equivalent for single and multiple plot figures.

Following is an example code (The font size is consistent between 1x1 and 2x1 figure, but decreases for 3x2 figure):

```
tiff("1x1.tif", width=3,height=2.5,units="in",res=600,pointsize=8,
compression="lzw",restoreConsole=T)
par(mfrow=c(1,1),mar=c(4,4,.5,.5)+0.1)
plot(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
dev.off()

tiff("2x1.tif", height=2.5*2,width=3,units="in",res=600,pointsize=8,
compression="lzw",restoreConsole=T)
par(mfrow=c(2,1),mar=c(2,4,2.5,0.5)+0.1)
plot(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),xaxt="n",xlab="")
par(mar=c(4,4,0.5,0.5)+0.1)
plot(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
dev.off()

tiff("3x2.tif", height=2.5*3,width=3*2,units="in",res=600,pointsize=8,
compression="lzw",restoreConsole=T)
par(mfrow=c(3,2),mar=c(.5,4,4,0.5)+0.1)
plot(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),xaxt="n",xlab="")
par(mar=c(.5,2,4,2.5)+0.1)
plot(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),xaxt="n",xlab="",yaxt="n",ylab="")
par(mar=c(2.5,4,2,0.5)+0.1)
plot(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),xaxt="n",xlab="")
par(mar=c(2.5,2,2,2.5)+0.1)
plot(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),xaxt="n",xlab="",yaxt="n",ylab="")
par(mar=c(4.5,4,0,0.5)+0.1)
plot(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
par(mar=c(4.5,2,0,2.5)+0.1)
plot(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),yaxt="n",ylab="")
dev.off()
```

Why is this happening?

P.S.: I'm not using `ggplot2` or `lattice` because I'm using my own error bar function on the "actual" figures (I can't remember why right now but I tried working with the ggplot2 error bars and didn't get what I wanted).

Comment: This is all described in the help pages and has nothing to do with `tiff()`. ?par ... see: "mfcol, mfrow" ...

In a layout with exactly two rows and columns the base value of "cex" is reduced by a factor of 0.83: if there are three or more of either rows or columns, the reduction factor is 0.66."

Comment: I had initially circumvented the problem my increasing "cex > 1" for each graph, it hadn't occured to me to do so in the call to "par". I'll look harder next time... though Backlin's suggestion to use "outer margin" is priceless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parameter controlling the overall relative size of objects in the plot (including text) is called `cex`. When you use many panels it is decreased by default, but it can be overridden by manually setting it to `1`.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,2), mar=c(.5,4,4,0.5)+0.1, cex=1)
```

#### Off-topic-tip

It looks like you should use `oma` (outer margin) rather than calling `par(mar=...)` between the calls to `plot`. I find it very useful, but hardly anyone seems to know of it. Also `ann=FALSE` turns off all anotations, `las=1` turns axis tick labels horizontal.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,2), oma=c(4.5, 4, 4, 2.5), mar=rep(.1, 4), cex=1, las=1)
plot(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), ann=FALSE, xaxt="n")
plot(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), ann=FALSE, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
plot(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), ann=FALSE, xaxt="n")
plot(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), ann=FALSE, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
plot(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), ann=FALSE)
plot(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), ann=FALSE, yaxt="n")
title("My plot", outer=TRUE)
mtext("X-axis label", 1, 3, outer=TRUE)
mtext("Y-axis label", 2, 3, outer=TRUE, las=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Just a warning. Care to ensure that all the graphs are on the same scale, as although they are not, they are going to be plotted and so we will be introducing erroneous data scales.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful (which it sounds like you did), you should vote it up or accept it, that's how the system works. See the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) section of the faq.

Comment: Manuel Ramón, thank you for the advice... although the example code isn't on the same scale, my data is.