# R: plot & the result is "plot.new has not been called yet"

Tags: r, graph, plot, syntax-error

Data (an abridged version):

```
m1 1
m2 2
m3 3
m4 0
m5 32
m6 12
m7 42
m8 56
m9 29
```

Note: 0 is supposed to represent a space in my graph

Code:

```
barplot(
  name,
  main="Mike vs. Ike" , 
  ylab="Number of criminal offences of two different people" , 
  xlab="" , 
  col=c("yellow" , "blue" ) , 
  beside=TRUE , 
  ylim= range(0 , 10) ,  
  las=2 , 
  axes=TRUE ,


   names.arg = c("Mike: number of offences in: 1 day"      , 
                    "Ike: number of offences in: 1 day"     ,
                    ""                       , 
                    "Mike: number of offences in: 1 week"      ,
                    "Ike: number of offences in: 1 week"     , 
                        ""                       ,
                        "Mike: number of offences in: 1 month"        ,
                        "Ike: number of offences in: 1 month"       , 
                        ""                       ,
                        "Mike: number of offences in: 1 year"     ,
                        "Mike: number of offences in: 1 year"   


           ) ,
             legend(
  "topright" , 
  c("Mike" , "Ike") , 
  col=c("yellow" , "green") , 
  pch=c(22:22) ,
  cex=0.75 )
)
```

Error I get:

```
Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

Billion $ question:

How can I scale my `names.arg` and `legend` to fit my graph

Danke in advance

**Don't read pass here (stack says too much code).**

apple orange apple orange apple orange apple orange apple orange apple orange apple orange apple orange apple orange apple orange apple orange apple orange apple orange apple orange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're calling `legend()` *inside* your call to `boxplot()` whereas it's supposed to be called *after*. At least that's what's giving you the error. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "scaling" the legend or names however.

Comment: "mike: number of offenses in: 1 year" gets "cut off when i view the image. My legend is too big and covers my graph is what i mean by that

Comment: @user3609325 Well, since your sample data doesn't seem sufficient to actually run the code, i'm not sure exactly what you're looking at. You can try placing elsewhere in the plotting space, or you can move it outside the plot into the margin by increasing the margins with par(mar=) and using par(xpd=NA) to plot outside the frame.

Comment: @user3609325 That's a bit vague. What exactly did you try? Did you read the documentation at `?par`? Did you call it before `boxplot()`?

Comment: i called par(mar) before boxplot. shall i call it after?

Comment: @user3609325 No. Before. But what values did you pass exactly?

Comment: par(mar=c(.5,4,4,0.5)+0.1)... got the idea from this question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534219/r-plot-font-size-changes-in-multiple-plot-figures

Comment: Then I don't see how that could throw an out of range error. Better to update your code to something a can copy and paste and run and get the same error.

Comment: don't worry about it. when I get better at R i will understand. THANK YOU for your help!! :)